# Action of limit of functors on arrows?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

$$\newcommand{\cSet}{\mathsf{Set}}$$
$$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$$

I'm trying to calculate the action of a limit of functors on morphisms. Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" says:

> The universal property of the limit construction is used to define the action
> of this functor on morphisms.

So I'm trying to figure out how to induce the action of the limit functor on morphisms.

###### Setup

Let $A \equiv ( 0 \xrightarrow{f} 1 )$ be a category, and let's consider the functor category $[A, \cSet]$. I wish to compute the limit of the diagram category $D \equiv (x \xrightarrow{g} y \xleftarrow{h} z)$ in the functor category $[A, \cSet]$. More precisely, suppose I have a diagram given by $K: D \to [A, \cSet]$. Let's call $K(x) = X$, $K(y) = Y$, $K(z) = Z$, $K(g) = \gamma$, $K(h) = \delta$. So this looks like:

$$
\begin{matrix}
[X0 \xrightarrow{Xf} X1] \Rightarrow_{\gamma} [Y0 \xrightarrow{Yf}{Y1}] 
\Leftarrow_{\delta} [Z0 \xrightarrow{Zf} Z1] 
\end{matrix}
$$

###### Calculating the limit

A limit to this diagram is given by a functor $L: [A, \cSet]$ along with three natural transformations $\lambda_x: L \Rightarrow X$, $\lambda_y: L \Rightarrow Y$, $\lambda_z: L \Rightarrow Z$. Let's first calculate the $L0, L1, Lf$.

- We calculate $L_0$ as the limit of the diagram: $X0 \xrightarrow{\gamma_0} Y0 \xleftarrow{\delta_0} Z0$.
- Similarly, we calculate $L_1$ as the limit of the diagram $X_1 \xrightarrow{\gamma_1} Y_1 \xleftarrow{\delta_1} Z_1$.
- Now, how do we calculate $L(f) \in \Hom(L0, L1)$?
- Since $L0$ is the limit of a diagram involving $X0, Y0, Z0$, we have the projections from $L0$ to $X0, Y0, Z0$.
- Next, we have the maps $X0 \xrightarrow{Xf} X1$, $Y0 \xrightarrow{Yf} Y1$, $Z0 \xrightarrow{Zf} Z1$ which allow us to map from $L0$ into $X1, Y1, Z1$.
- If we can prove that this allows us to have a cone with apex $L0$ and base $X1 \xrightarrow{\gamma_1} Y1 \xleftarrow{\delta1} Z1$, we then get a factorization map of the apex of the cone ($L0$) to the apex of the limit ($L1$) which is the map from $L0$ to $L1$ we are looking for.
- How do we show that $L0$ is an apex of the cone with base $X1 \xrightarrow{\gamma_1} Y1 \xleftarrow{\delta1} Z1$?

I'm stuck at this point; I don't really know if I'm doing the right thing in attempting to calculate what $L_f$ is supposed to be.

Comment: Are you just asking for, given $f: X \to Y$, how to define the natural map $\mathrm{Lim}f: \mathrm{Lim}X \to \mathrm{Lim}Y$?  In this case, $X$ and $Y$ are functors and $f$ is a natural transformation.

Comment: How is what you are trying to do connected with trying to "induce the action of the limit functor on morphisms"?

Comment: The arrow $Lf$ that I'm looking for is the action of the limit functor $L$ on the morphism $f \in Hom(0, 1)$ [in $A$]

Comment: @Randall To be honest, I am confused. I don't believe that's what I'm looking for, but I could be wrong :) I believe I have components $f_j: X_j \to Y_j$ which I'm trying to assemble into a $\operatorname{Lim}~f: \operatorname{Lim}X \to \operatorname{Lim}Y$

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I think your last comment is right, but those components are the pieces of a natural transformation of functors.  Without naturality, you won't get anywhere.  I think your setup is wrong.